# How to disable pagination in Wordpress' API results?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I have the following code, however, regardless of the `numberpost` in `$args`, I always get the default number of records set in my settings which is 6 and I have 200+ records.  Is there any simple way to disable this or to override the numberposts in settings?

```
function fs_ski_resorts_data(){
   
    $args = array(
        'numberposts'   => 999,
        'post_type'     => 'fs_ski_resorts',
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    $fs_ski_resorts = get_posts($args);
    $fs_ski_resorts_data = [];
    $i = 0;
    
    while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        $fs_ski_resorts_data[$i]['fs_ski_resort_name'] =  get_field('fs_ski_resort_data_fs_name') ?: get_field('fs_ski_resort_data_osm_name');
        $i++;
    endwhile;
    
    return $fs_ski_resorts_data;
}


add_action('rest_api_init', function(){
    register_rest_route('fs/v1', 'fs_ski_resorts', [
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'fs_ski_resorts_data',
    ]);
});
```

Comment: numberposts Is not a supported parameter of WP_Query. You need to use posts_per_page. but be warned that having an endpoint that queries 1000 posts is dangerous, and potentially makes it very easy to bring your site down. Your endpoint should implement pagination and your application should be built to work with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `WP_Query` directly, you should use `posts_per_page` and *not* `numberposts` — it is an alias for `posts_per_page`, but only used with [`get_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/).

```php
// These work, but I strongly advise against using 999:
$fs_ski_resorts = get_posts( array( 'numberposts' => 999 ) );
$fs_ski_resorts = get_posts( array( 'posts_per_page' => 999 ) );
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 999 ) );

// This doesn't work:
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'numberposts' => 999 ) );
```

As for disabling the pagination, via `WP_Query`, it can be done using the [`nopaging` parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#pagination-parameters), but I suggest you to always enable pagination, which defaults to *max* 100 posts/items per page in the REST API. See https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/#pagination-parameters:

> Large queries can hurt site performance, so `per_page` is **capped at
> 100 records**. If you wish to retrieve more than 100 records, for
> example to build a client-side list of all available categories, you
> may make multiple API requests and combine the results within your
> application.

Comment: Thank you.  I changed to posts_per_page but not I get everything whereas you state it should default to 100?, right?

Comment: In `WP_Query`, the default `posts_per_page` value is based on your setting at Settings → Reading → "Blog pages show at most", i.e. the database option named `posts_per_page`. And you could also use `'posts_per_page' => -1` which is equivalent to `'nopaging' => true`, to disable pagination, but once again, you should not disable pagination.

Comment: For core endpoints like [`GET /wp/v2/posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#list-posts), the default `per_page` value is 10 and its default maximum value is 100, and these values will be used with the `posts_per_page` parameter for `WP_Query`. For custom endpoints like yours, it's up to you to handle the `per_page` value (and for example like the core endpoints, reject values above 100), e.g. do `function fs_ski_resorts_data( $request )` and then `'posts_per_page' => $request['per_page']`.

Comment: Oh and for completeness, use the `paged` parameter to actually paginate the results. E.g. `'paged' => $request['page']`. And note that `per_page` and `page` are available to all custom endpoints.